# Why do I get extra axes or axis borders?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I construct a chart that has only one vertical axis. This axis consists from several white ticks and one vertical red bar. Here is the code:

```
svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')
  .attr('class', 'axis-right')
  .call(
    d3
      .axisRight()
      .scale(scaleYreverse)
      .ticks(10)
      .tickFormat((x) => `${x}шт`)
      .tickSize(-width)
      .tickPadding(5)
  )
  .selectAll('text')
  .style('stroke', 'orange');
```

However actually I see 3 red bars instead of single red bar. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Please tell me how to leave only one vertical line on the chart?

Live example [is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xrmnih?file=index.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code responsible for the issue is:

```
.tickSize(-width)
```

From the doco on [`tickSize`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSize):

> If size is specified, sets the inner and **outer** [*my emphasis*] tick
> size to the specified value and returns the axis. If size is not
> specified, returns the current inner tick size, which defaults to 6.

So when you set `tickSize(-width)` it affects the ticks at the top and bottom of the axis and makes them as wide as the inner ticks.

Instead, set the widths on the [inner](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSizeInner) and [outer](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSizeOuter) ticks independently with:

```
.tickSizeInner(-width) 
.tickSizeOuter(6) // set this to -40, 0 etc to see different effects
```

Which sets the top and bottom ticks to 6 (juts out a little rightward) and the inner ticks are now white and extend fully leftward into the plot.

Working example:

```js
const padding = 60;
const width = 400;
const height = 400;
const data = [
  [90, 55, 8],
  [1200, 62, 11],
  [666, 84, 5],
  [300, 123, 11],
  [400, 255, 7],
  [123, 333, 11],
  [600, 390, 11],
  [700, 412, 15],
  [1222, 550, 11],
  [56, 877, 2],
  [1000, 1232, 22],
  [1100, 25, 7],
  [23, 345, 11],
  [1300, 444, 4],
];

const xCollection = data.map((val) => val[0]);
const yCollection = data.map((val) => val[1]);
const rCollection = data.map((val) => val[2]);

const scaleX = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(xCollection)])
  .range([0, height]);

const scaleY = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(yCollection)])
  .range([0, height]);

const scaleYreverse = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.max(yCollection), 0])
  .range([0, height]);

const box = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('div')
  .style('padding', padding + 'px')
  .style('width', width + 'px')
  .style('height', height + 'px');

const svg = box.append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

// svg
//   .append('g')
//   .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
//   .attr('class', 'axis-bottom')
//   .call(
//     d3
//       .axisBottom()
//       .scale(scaleX)
//       .ticks(10)
//       .tickFormat((x) => `${x}м`)
//       .tickSize(-height)
//       .tickPadding(5)
//   )
//   .selectAll('text')
//   .style('text-anchor', 'end')
//   .attr('dx', '-.8em')
//   .attr('dy', '.15em')
//   .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)')
//   .style('stroke', 'magenta');

svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')
  .attr('class', 'axis-right')
  .call(
    d3
      .axisRight()
      .scale(scaleYreverse)
      .ticks(10)
      .tickFormat((x) => `${x}шт`)
      .tickSizeInner(-width) 
      .tickSizeOuter(6) 
      .tickPadding(5)
  )
  .selectAll('text')
  .style('stroke', 'orange');
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  background: rgb(194, 235, 235);
  overflow: visible;
}

svg .tick line {
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```